# Why does Internet Explorer ignore body font size?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm building Magento website and it's working perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it's not showing correctly in IE9, IE8.

Body font size is set to `12px` but IE seems to ignore it completely.

Here's the CSS of body element:

```
body {
  background: url(../images/background/bkgd.gif) repeat-x scroll left top #FFFFFF;
  font: 12px/1.55 arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the [website](http://no1pizza.com/cottridgehomw/). Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are inline styles in your HTML/Template. View source and search for 20px I found on line 99 something like below:

```
<div a align="right">
            <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">Your local No1Pizza is <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;"><a href="/pizza.html">Wolverhampton.<span/>
            <a style="font-weight:bold; font-size:8pt;" href="/index.php/emptybasket/ ">
            (Not your desired shop?)
            </a>
            </div>       </div>
```

You REALLY need to clean up the code. Also pay attention on the wrong closing tag `<span/>` above.